# Why are the ship names suffixed with "Go"?

Tags: one-piece

The names of all the ships in One Piece are suffixed with *Go* in Japanese. For example, Going Merry Go, Thousand Sunny Go, Moby Dick Go. However, the English version drops the *Go* suffix. This suggested it might be a honorific used to address a ship, but I couldn't find any source that says "Go" is a honorific.

There's also no mention of Go on the [Japanese ship-naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_ship-naming_conventions) page on Wikipedia, and I couldn't find anything like this in any other place either.

I don't recall this being explained in the manga. Is there any explanation for this use of "Go", with a reliable source for reference?

Comment: The character used for it is 号, is a counting marker. I don't know what that indicates, but it might help. It's also not used for all of the ships. The government ships, at least, don't seem to use that (though I could be wrong).

Comment: @kuwaly Well, yeah, but from what I seem to recall, the Marine ships don't have a name per se. They are just called Marine ships, or named after the Captain, such as Vice Admiral Garp's ship.

Comment: Probably they mean "go" in english and not in japanese! :P

Answer (score 3):

`号` or the `-go` suffix is normally used to name naval (aka war) ships in Japan. If you want get the equivalent in English, is the same as *S.S. Name of the Ship* used by the US. One Piece is just following the same naming convencion.

Comment: Do you have some kind of reference, or is it some "general knowledge" thing that a Japanese just happens to know? I have also read about this in some forums, but couldn't find any reliable source.

Comment: @MaskedMan very late response, but [Japanese Wikipedia for 号](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%B7) mentioned "鉄道・バス・船舶などの乗り物の愛称につける接尾辞" (A suffix for vehicle's nickname; trains, buses, ships, etc)